# CSS: shortening the :before pseudo-element?

Tags: html, css

I'm a bit of a beginner, and I'm using `:before` for paragraph numbers. I have different styles for paragraphs, and I want some paragraphs to be numbered, and other paragraphs to be un-numbered. Here's a toy example: http://jsfiddle.net/afdBk/

My question is: do you know of a way to avoid putting the same lengthy `:before` litany after every paragraph type I want to be numbered? Could I simply make up a selector for it (something like `.pgfno`), put all the styling there, and then call back to this selector in the `:before`s? This would make things a lot cleaner and easier to read.

Thanks.

Comment: I don't quite get the purpose of the different paragraph types. Could you explain them?

Comment: It's just a fake example. The real document is very long and has a lot of different styles throughout.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can assign rules to multiple selectors at once: ([jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DpDwz/))

```
.maintext p.type1:before, .maintext p.type2:before, .maintext p.type3:before {
    position: absolute;
    text-indent: 0px;
    left: 45px;
    padding-top: 1px;
    font-size: 80%;
    color: #888888;
    counter-increment: pgf;
}
```

You can also set several classes on one single element ([jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HHyq4/)):

```
.numbered:before {
    position: absolute;
    text-indent: 0px;
    left: 45px;
    padding-top: 1px;
    font-size: 80%;
    color: #888888;
    counter-increment: pgf;
    content: counter(pgf);
}

<p class="type1 numbered">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet...</p>
```

Comment: And as for the several classes thing: oh, that's good. Thanks again.

Comment: I'm glad it worked for you! If this information solved your problem, consider clicking the checkmark under its score.